# Android Studio apk analyzer shows smaller size than finder does

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I use Android Studio to analysis release apk and I get below info.

```
APK size:13.8MB, Download Size:13.4MB
```

However if I use `ll`, I get below info

```
-rw-r--r--  1 coxier  staff    14M May 28 13:04 release.apk
```

I want to know why there are three size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size on disk is usually bigger than the actual file in most situations. This is because the way files are stored on the disk in tracks and clusters.

So, you shouldn't be worried about the size on disk. APK analyzer gives you the correct APK size which would be available for users to download.

Comment: And if I upload my apk to other people, they receive 13.4 or 13.8 MB?

Comment: The user's will be downloading 13.4MB of data.

Answer (score 1):

`Raw File Size` which is just the APK on-disk size. In your case it is

```
APK size:13.8MB
```

The `Download size` shows an estimate of how much data will be used to download your app by taking into account compression applied by the Play Store and it is

```
Download Size:13.4MB
```

I am not much sure about `ll`, That may be because of the size difference in the disk.

more info @ [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer)